# How to convert number in json to string in typescript interface

Tags: typescript

```
{
   "id": 13,
   "name": "horst",
}
```

to

```
 interface A {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

when `A` json converts to `A` object, I expected to convert `id` from number to string automatically. but it doesn't convert.

i want to convert from number to string by type infer. when a json parse to object.
how can i do it?

ps. sorry my English is poor..

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't include any type information at runtime. You need to use something like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) to perform runtime coercion of parsed types into typed data structures.